# How to access product's meta data when deleting a WooCommerce product?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm not able to access the individual products for an order before the order is deleted.

```
add_action('before_delete_post', 'removeCheckDetail', 99, 2 );
function removeCheckDetail( $order_id ) {

global $woocommerce; 
global $wpdb; 

// $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // This Works
error_log("Starting " .$order->get_id()); 

$order_items = $order->get_items(); 
error_log("Count: " .count($order_items)); // Returns 0

// Loop through order line items
foreach( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
    error_log("CartItemKey: " .$item->get_name()); // No Loops
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working.

```
add_action('before_delete_post', 'removeCheckDetail', 10, 1 );
function removeCheckDetail( $order_id ) {

global $woocommerce; 
global $wpdb; 

$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order_items = $order->get_items(); 

// Loop through order line items
foreach( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {

   $url = $item->get_meta('Check Detail');  

   parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $array );

   $key = strstr($array['ck_item'], '"', true);

   $wpdb->check_detail = "{$wpdb->prefix}check_detail";

   $wpdb->delete($wpdb->check_detail, array('cart_item_key' => $key));
 }
```

}